# Why getting None while using list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have list of  dictionaries and I would like to create a new list of dictionaries by using conditional list comprehension.

Examples of the list of dictionaries are:

```
d1 = [{'id': '1', 'co': '1', 'w': '10'}, {'id': '5', 'co': '2', 'w':'60'}]
d2 = [{'id': '1', 'na': 'Bi', 'teac': ' D'}]
```

As an output, desired output is:

```
 d_new = [{'id': '1', 'co': '1', 'w': '10', 'na': 'Bi', 'teac': ' D'}]
```

My initial approach was to use a comprehension as below:

```
[d1.update({'na':r['na'],'teac':r['teac']}) for d in d1 for r in d2 if d['co'] == r['id']]
```

However, I am getting `[None, None]` as an output.

Any ideas how to fix this to get the desired output?

Just a quick update:

I meant this instead of the one below:

```
 [d.update({'na':r['na'],'teac':r['teac']}) for d in d1 for r in d2 if d['co'] == r['id']]
```

Comment: `update()` modifies the dictionary in place, it doesn't return the dictionary.

Comment: Because `d1.update(` **returns `None`**. Don't use list-comprehensions for side-effects

Comment: `dict.update` returns `None`.  In general, you should avoid calling functions with side-effects inside of dict/list comprehensions.

Comment: You should be getting an error, because `d1` is a list, and lists don't have an `update` method.

Comment: Did you mean `d.update`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I meant `d.update`

Answer (score 0):

for one your code makes no sense in relation to what your output should be, anyway for the answer to your question of why [None, None] list comprehension returns a list which holds return of ur statement d1.update(something) which is inplace update and returns nothing (None), and the loop runs twice since there is 2 items in d1 and 1 item in d2 (2*1) (i.e if you dont have the if statement at the end considering if it will return [None]) so you get 2 Nones in a list check the value of d1 at the end youll see it has changed